# Hover on edge's label in cytoscape

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Right now I have a warning sign as part of the edge's label, I would like it be able to show qtip on hover (not hover on edge, just the label of it), is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.  Events are per-element.  You would have to determine the label's co-ordinates yourself and fire your own event.